# Issue with Parsing JSON Data in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm currently working on a project where I need to parse JSON data in Python, and I'm facing an issue with the `'json.loads()`' function. I've retrieved a JSON string from an API, and when I try to parse it using `'json.loads()'` , I encounter the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "script.py", line 10, in <module>`

`parsed_data = json.loads(json_string)`

`File "/path/to/python/lib/json/`**`init`**`.py", line 339,`

`in loads`

`return _default_decoder.decode(s)`

`File "/path/to/python/lib/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode`

`obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())`

`File "/path/to/python/lib/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode`

`obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)`

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Here's a snippet of the JSON data I'm trying to parse:

`{  'key': 'value' , 'another_key': 123  }gt`

I suspect the issue is related to the single quotes used in the JSON string, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. I've tried using `'json.loads(json_string.replace("'", """))'` to replace single quotes with double quotes, but the error persists.

Comment: Why is this tagged with php, javascript, html , css? You've indicated your attempting to parse in Python.

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON requires double-quote characters `{ "key": "value" }`. The correct way to "fix" that is to fix the source of the data. Where does it come from? Why is it produced incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this is about single quotes, because correct JSON has double quotes around strings (incl. keys). You also provided the solution, but you JSON has `gt` at the end, which is unexpected.

Example of solution:

```
import json

def parse_improper_json(json_str):
    json_str = json_str.replace("'", '"').replace('}gt', '}')
    parsed_json = json.loads(json_str)
    return parsed_json

print(parse_improper_json("{  'key': 'value' , 'another_key': 123  }gt"))
```

But keep in mind that might be not production-grade solution, because the JSON could contain single or double quotes in values, or `}gt` string somewhere in the middle or could be not an object at all. Consider these cases in your case.